# A pulse or cron job for Rails app running in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cron, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need some code executed once per day. Can be more than once a day and missing a day isn't the end of the world. That code will make sure users get some bonus points based on certain criteria. I'll keep track if they've already received the bonus points so it doesn't double up..

Some simple cron job calling a particular controller once in a while is perfect:

```
curl http://localhost/tasks/pulse
```

Of course a real crontab entry works great. Or is there an internal mechanism for this kind of thing in Rails? I'm using the latest stable Rails (currently 3.2.9).

The only wrinkle is this needs to work in Heroku too.

I just noticed [Heroku's Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). Looks great for Heroku. I can just run those tasks in my dev/test environment manually. Is this the best way to handle pulses/cron jobs in Rails? With rake tasks? Easy to incorporate running rake tasks in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) works great and is easy to set up!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of how you can set it up, and how i'm currently using it on a prod environment

Add the sidekiq and sidekiq-cron gems to your Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-cron'
```

Create a worker class for your tasks:

```rb
class RakeTaskWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(task)
    output = `bundle exec rails #{task} 2>&1`
    status = $?.exitstatus
    if status.zero?
      Sidekiq.logger.info("Rake task '#{task}' executed successfully.")
    else
      Sidekiq.logger.error("Rake task '#{task}' failed with status #{status}: #{output}")
    end
  end
end
```

Define your cron job in `config/schedule.yml`:

```yaml
daily_bonus_worker:
  cron: "0 0 * * *"
  class: "RakeTaskWorker"
  args:
    - "generate:daily_bonus"
```

https://github.com/sidekiq-cron/sidekiq-cron

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this gem called [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) its a Ruby gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and deploying cron jobs. It's well maintained, not used it on Heroku myself but worth a look.

You can do loads of stuff like

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

Comment: Looks amazing, and its all within rails? No external things need to run to give whenever its pulse? Will it work in heroku?

Comment: Actually having looked into it further here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619754/whenever-gem-running-cron-jobs-on-heroku) looks like its not suitable for use on heroku as the whenever gem is just a nice ruby way to write cron jobs and deploy them, the crontab would not persist on heroku. Sorry but I guess my initial answer was not much a help, a good solution if you're not using heroku in future though maybe.

Comment: What about using http://godrb.com/ to create a worker that is constantly running and just makes an http request once a day in a loop, that could work.