# How to move scheduler.rake into a more reliable background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Basically... I just want to **exactly** move what is in scheduler.rake into a worker because I am hoping it is faster and more reliable.

What is the quickest way to do this? I am on Rails 3

Nothing fancy. Just quick.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

in your Gemfile.

`gem 'whenever', :require => false`

This will create an initial `config/schedule.rb` file for you.

```
every 3.hours do
  # call background job
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  # call background job
end

every :hour do 
  # call background job
end

every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do 
  # call background job
end

every '0 0 27-31 * *' do
  # call background job
end
```

I hope that this helps. 
Happy Hacking

Comment: it does, it has to be set up right take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8619815/1380867 for more info.

Comment: you can also also use Heroku Scheduler  to queue your jobs every 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroku Scheduler then you can configure what type of dyno starts for each job.

Note that jobs ran on Scheduler should complete before next scheduled task or they will be terminated.

For more advanced clock related work please see this (but it's not trivial): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes

Comment: I don't like how scheduler is 'best effort' I want to quickly kick off reliable background processes.