# How to run rails rake task more frequently than 10 minutes on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

There's a straight forward explanation of why cron jobs and tasked scheduled with whenever gem [won't work on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619815/5783745)

Is there any way to schedule a rake task to run more frequently than every 10 minutes (the minimum frequency heroku scheduler offers), for example every 1 minute?

Comment: You could use RabbitMQ and set up a dead letter exchange...

Comment: @jvillian these are both new terms to me. I'll google now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [Clockwork gem](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) and Heroku Procfile.

- in your `lib/clock.rb`, you can do something like:

```
every(1.minute, 'Run task') do
  Rake::Task['namespace:task'].invoke
end
```

- then add `clock: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb` to your Heroku Procfile

Clockwork supports a lot of time variations.

Answer (score 0):

I think @ollaollu's method is probably superior, but for future reference what worked for me was to [use a `Procfile` to run an infinite loop on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64657455/5783745), and that effectively runs a process every 5 seconds and even works after `heroku restart`.